# spaCy nlp pipeline order of operations

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, lemmatization

Does anyone have a chronological list of operations performed by

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(text)
```

I can see the major components with `nlp.pipe_names`

```
['tagger', 'parser', 'ner']
```

and an alphabetical list of factory operations with `nlp.factories`

```
{'merge_entities': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'merge_noun_chunks': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'ner': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'parser': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'sbd': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'sentencizer': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'similarity': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'tagger': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'tensorizer': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'textcat': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>,
 'tokenizer': <function spacy.language.Language.<lambda>>}
```

but I can't figure out when the **lemmatizer** is invoked. 
Lemmatization has to happen after **tokenization** and **POS tagging**, and it will run with the **parser** and **ner** disabled. The spaCy [pipeline docs](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#pipelines) don't mention it at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more recent answer, the pipeline design as of spaCy v3.4 is explained on the spaCy site [here](https://spacy.io/models#design). I've reproduced some important parts below should the link become invalid.

> The spaCy v3 trained pipelines are designed to be efficient and
> configurable. For example, multiple components can share a common
> “token-to-vector” model and it’s easy to swap out or disable the
> lemmatizer. The pipelines are designed to be efficient in terms of
> speed and size and work well when the pipeline is run in full.
>
> When modifying a trained pipeline, it’s important to understand how
> the components depend on each other. Unlike spaCy v2, where the
> tagger, parser and ner components were all independent, some v3
> components depend on earlier components in the pipeline. As a result,
> disabling or reordering components can affect the annotation quality
> or lead to warnings and errors.

### CNN/CPU pipeline design

[image: spaCy v3 pipeline]

> In the `sm/md/lg` models:
>
> - The `tagger`, `morphologizer` and `parser` components listen to the `tok2vec` component. If the lemmatizer is trainable (v3.3+),
>   `lemmatizer` also listens to `tok2vec`.
> - The `attribute_ruler` maps `token.tag` to `token.pos` if there is no `morphologizer`. The `attribute_ruler` additionally makes sure
>   whitespace is tagged consistently and copies `token.pos` to
>   `token.tag` if there is no tagger. For English, the attribute ruler
>   can improve its mapping from `token.tag` to `token.pos` if dependency
>   parses from a `parser` are present, but the parser is not required.
> - The `lemmatizer` component for many languages requires `token.pos` annotation from either `tagger`+`attribute_ruler` or `morphologizer`.
>   The `ner` component is independent with its own internal `tok2vec`
>   layer.

### Transformer pipeline design

> In the transformer (`trf`) models, the `tagger`, `parser` and `ner`
> (if present) all listen to the `transformer` component. The
> `attribute_ruler` and `lemmatizer` have the same configuration as in
> the CNN models.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is more complicated than I originally thought, but now I will explain it in detail.

SpaCy lemmatization usually is performed based on a lookup table. That means that is independent on the pipeline components and it lemmatization happens before the pipe. However, English language and Greek language are designed such that a rule based lemmatization can be performed when pos tag is available. That means that if tagger is enabled then we can take advantage of the POS tag in order to find the best lemma matching the word based on its' tag. In this case, lemmatization happens just after the tagger pipeline component.

Briefly, if tagger is disabled the we follow a static lemmatization procedure based on a lookup table that matches words to their lemmas and lemmatization happens before any pipeline component. Contrary to that, when tagger is enabled the lemmatization procedure is rule based and dependent on the POS tag, so it happens after tagger. I repeat that this case can happen only for certain languages that support rule based lemmatization such as English and Greek language.

A code example:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
nlp.remove_pipe('parser')
# uncommenting the following line means we go to rule based lemmatization
# nlp.remove_pipe('tagger')
nlp.remove_pipe('ner')
doc = nlp('those are random words')
for token in doc:
    print(token.lemma_)
```

Output with line commented out: those be random word

Output with line without comment: that be random word

Hope it is clarified now.

Comment: I thought so, too - but if you _don't_ remove the `'tagger'`, then "these" and "those" retain their native form. That is, their lemmas don't become "this" and "that" unless the tagger pipeline component is disabled.

Comment: Sorry, I missed something. I updated my answer and I think that now it is 100% complete and can be marked as accepted answer.

Comment: That makes more sense, and explains the behavior of "I'm meeting him at tomorrow's meeting" - POS tagging causes each occurrence of "meeting" to be lemmatized differently. I can't accept this as answering the question, though, as I'm still looking for something of a tokenization/pipeline workflow diagram. But thank you, this helps!

Comment: Glad it helped you! Can you please explain more your question? What is missing from the diagram in the url https://spacy.io/assets/img/pipeline.svg that you would like to know?